# What is the problem in my ngModel when I want to define a variable?

Tags: html, angular

I want to use ngModel, but I have a problem.
This code is not running and it gives me an error.

This is my code:

`contact-form.component.html`:

```html
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input ngModel #firstName="firstName" (change)="log(firstName)" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">comment</label>
        <textarea id="comment" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
</form>

</div>
```

`contact-form.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  log(f) {
    console.log(f);
  }

}
```

and this error display in console:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "firstName" ("  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input ngModel [ERROR ->]#firstName="firstName" (change)="log(firstName)" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  "): ng:///AppModule/ContactFormComponent.html@4:23
```

What can I do?

Comment: `#firstName="firstName"` should be omitted entirely *or* just be `#firstName` *or* `#firstName="ngModel"` but that depends on how you want to use it or if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

modify your input tag in the form like the following :

```
<input  #firstName="ngModel" (change)="log(firstName)" 
 type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

Note: if you you want to have Two-way data binding ( **[(ngModel)]="propName"** ):

```
<input  #firstName="ngModel" (change)="log(firstName)" [(ngModel)]="firstName"
     type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- for your input tag use this. this will breaking down Two-Way data binding.

  ```
  <input #firstName (change)="log(firstName)" type="text">

  - and to display its content use it as interpolation syntax in your template. 

  {{firstName.value}}
  - after you done text input press enter and results will be in interpolation.
  ```
- Second way of doing this is like..
- in this case you need to define your property name in your component class too.

  ```
  private firstName;
  ```

  - and in your template file

    ```
     <input [ngModel]="firstName" (ngModelChange)="firstName = $event" >

     {{ firstName }}
    ```
- make sure you import `FormsModule` in main app module of your project.

  ```
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  ```
- If you want to access template reference variable in your component.ts file then your have to use @ViewChild () directives. and result of this available only in ngAfterViewInit() life cycle method.

  ```
   @ViewChild ('firstName', { static: false}  ) inputRefElm : ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit(){
       console.log(this.inputRefElm.nativeElement.value);
   }
  ```

Comment: Did you mean banana in a box? `[(firstName)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="firstName" #firstName (change)="log(firstName)" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
```